# Return a synthetic response then fetch and cache object in Varnish?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm wondering if my (possibly strange) use case is possible to implement in Varnish with VCL. My application depends on receiving responses from a cacheable API server with very low latencies (i.e. sub-millisecond if possible). The application is written in such a way that an "empty" response is handled appropriately (and is a valid response in some cases), and the API is designed in such a way that non-empty responses are valid for a long time (i.e. days).

So, what I would like to do is configure varnish so that it:

1. Attempts to look up (and return) a cached response for the given API call
2. On a cache miss, immediately return an "empty" response, and queue the request for the backend
3. On a future call to a URL which was a cache miss in #2, return the now-cached response

Is it possible to make Varnish act in this way using VCL alone? If not, is it possible to write a VMOD to do this (and if so, pointers, tips, etc, would be greatly appreciated!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it with VCL alone, but with VCL and some client logic you could manage it quite easily, I think.

In vcl_miss, return an empty document using error 200 and set a response header called X-Try-Again in the default case.
In the client app, when receiving an empty response with X-Try-Again set, request the same resource asynchronously but add a header called X-Always-Fetch to the request. Your app does not wait for the response or do anything with it once it arrives.
Also in vcl_miss, check for the presence of the same X-Always-Fetch header. If present, return (fetch) instead of the empty document. This will request the content from the back end and cache it for future requests.

I also found this article which may provide some help though the implementation is a bit clunky to me compared to just using your client code: http://lassekarstensen.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/varnish-trick-serve-stale-content-while-refetching/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a similar use case and am wondering if you know if anything has changed in the last 5 years to have Varnish handle this itself as opposed to having the client re-request.